# Output Video Size Huge Using HEVC Encoder on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, hevc

I have a project that currently uses the H.264 encoder to record video on iOS.  I wanted to try using the new HEVC encoder in iOS 11 to reduce file sizes, but have found that using the HEVC encoder causes file sizes to balloon enormously.  [Here's a project on GitHub that shows the issue - it simultaneously writes frames from the camera to files using the H.264 and H.265 (HEVC) encoders, and the resulting file sizes are printed to the console.](https://github.com/jpetrich/HEVCDemo)

The AVFoundation classes are setup like this:

```
class VideoWriter {
    var avAssetWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput
    var avAssetWriter: AVassetWriter
    init() {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            avAssetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecType.hevc, AVVideoHeightKey:720, AVVideoWidthKey:1280])
        }
        avAssetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        do {
            let url = directory.appendingPathComponent(UUID.init().uuidString.appending(".hevc"))
            avAssetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(url: url, fileType: AVFileType.mp4)
            avAssetWriter.add(avAssetWriterInput)
            avAssetWriter.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not initialize AVAssetWriter \(error)")
        }
    }
...
```

and then frames are written like this:

```
    func write(sampleBuffer buffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        if avAssetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown {
            avAssetWriter.startWriting()
            avAssetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buffer))
         }
        if avAssetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            avAssetWriterInput.append(buffer)
        }
    }
```

as they come in to the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.  At the qualities I'm recording (720p or 1080p) the file size of an HEVC-encoded video should be 40-60% of an identical H.264-encoded video, and I am seeing this when I use the default camera app on iOS, but when I use AVAssetWriter as above (or in the project linked above) I'm seeing file sizes be about three times larger with HEVC than with H.264.  Either I am doing something wrong or the HEVC encoder is not working properly.  Am I missing something or is there a workaround to get HEVC working through AVFoundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the bitrate, etc.?
As below:

```
NSUInteger bitrate = 50 * 1024 * 1024;  // 50 Mbps
NSUInteger keyFrameInterval = 30;
NSString *videoProfile = AVVideoProfileLevelH264HighAutoLevel;
NSString *codec = AVVideoCodecH264;
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    videoProfile = (NSString *)kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel;
    codec = AVVideoCodecTypeHEVC;
}

NSDictionary *codecSettings = @{AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @(bitrate),
                              AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: @(keyFrameInterval),
                              AVVideoProfileLevelKey: videoProfile};
NSDictionary *videoSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: codec,
                              AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: codecSettings,
                              AVVideoWidthKey: @((NSInteger)resolution.width),
                              AVVideoHeightKey: @((NSInteger)resolution.height)};

AVAssetWriterInput *videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
...
```

As far as I understand, with the same bitrate, the file size should be the same for H264 and HEVC, but the quality of the HEVC should be better.

Comment: I got a response from Apple along similar lines.  Apparently the default bitrate for H.264 is 5mbit and HEVC is 30mbit.  I will report back and accept your answer if I try this out and it works!

Comment: @jpetrichsr i wish i would have discovered this sooner. The difference in defaults is outrageous. You wouldn't assume that simply changing a codec flag would cause completely wild outcomes in the *opposite* direction you're anticipating. I could see the same output size being reasonable by bumping the bitrate to take advantage of h265, but this can really burn you if you aren't paying close attention.

Comment: Hello everybody, I am trying this same thing (except in Swift) and the weird thing is that when using h.264 I can get a specific video file (1 minute) down to 10MB while with hevc no matter how low I put the bitrate, it won't go lower than 19MB. With h.264, it goes down to 6MB and after that the bitrate doesn't decrease the file size anymore. With hevc / h.265 this just happens way, way earlier. Any way around it?

Comment: @unixb0y did you get any further with this? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: @skeg0 nope I dont think so :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `exportSession.fileLengthLimit = 1048576 * 10 //10 MB`

10MB is hard coded number. Use according to your required bitrate.